# Here Maps API - group.getBoundingBox is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, maps, here-api, heremaps

Trying to group map Markers then focus and zoom on the group.

I have followed the Docs: [Zooming to a Set of Markers](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/zoom-to-set-of-markers)

script

```js
    public viewGroupMarkers() {
        // CREATE MARKERS
        const toronto = new H.map.Marker({lat:43.7,  lng:-79.4});
        const boston = new H.map.Marker({lat:42.35805, lng:-71.0636});
        const washington = new H.map.Marker({lat:38.8951, lng:-77.0366});
        // CREATE GROUP
        const group = new H.map.Group();
        group.addObjects([toronto, boston, washington]);
        // ADD GROUP TO MAP
        this.map.addObject(group);
        // GET VIEW BOUND GROUP
        this.map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
          bounds: group.getBoundingBox()
        });
      }
```

...but when trying to `group.getBoundingBox` I get an error:

```
core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: group.getBoundingBox is not a function
    at HereMapsComponent.viewGroupMarkers (here-maps.component.ts:286:21)
    at TripMapComponent.setGroupViewBounds (trip-map.component.ts:91:28)
    at CardMapTripComponent.setMarkers (card-map-trip.component.ts:30:18)
    at CardMapTripComponent_Template_app_trip_map_isReady_15_listener (template.html:28:11)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15307:1)
    at Object.wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault [as next] (core.js:15345:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBoundingBox` method was introduced in Group object in the latest (3.1) version of API.

I think you still load legacy 3.0 API.

You have two options:

1. Migrate to version 3.1 (recommended). This [migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/migration.html) should help you to switch to version 3.1.
2. change method to `getBounds()`